# On the number of integral points of analytic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

Consider a curve over some number field $\mathbb{K}$. By Falting's Theorem, if the genus $g$ is greater than $1$, the curve has only finitely many integral points. Moreover, as shown in *Bilu, Y. et al., Characterizing algebraic curves with infinitely many integral points.*, it is possible to characterise the algebraic curves with genus $g \leq 1$ having infinitely many integral points.

The definition of algebraic curve involves the zero set of some polynomial, so a natural generalisation is the concept of [analytic variety](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analytic_variety#:%7E:text=Complex%20analytic%20varieties%20are%20locally,finite%20set%20of%20holomorphic%20functions.), where we consider the zero set of some analytic function.

My question is: is it possible to generalise the above results for analytic varieties over number fields, in order to establish - in particular - whether an analytic curve has finitely/infinitely many integral points?

(With analytic curve, I mean a curve $y=f(x)$ with $f$ real/complex analytic)

Comment: What is an analytic variety over a number field? Especially a projective curve (in order to have a notion of genus)?

Comment: With analytic variery over a number field I mean the zero locus of an analytic function $f:\mathbb{K}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$, together with a sheaf defined analogously to the one in the wikipedia link above. I do not know if there is any well established definition of genus in such a case.

Comment: You are asking for a generalization of Faltings' theorem. Any idea of a possible formulation?

Comment: My idea was (assuming that there is a generalisation of the notion of genus for analytic varieties (I'd say, maybe defined via Hodge numbers, extended to this kind of space)): Consider an analytic curve with genus g. Then, if $g$ is $> 1$, (and - if necessary - other hypothesis are satisfied), the curve has only finitely many integral points. Otherwise, if $g \leq 1$, under some conditions analogous to the ones in the paper cited above, the curve has infinitely many integral points

Comment: Maybe, instead of genus there is some other invariant which work better for analutic spaces

Comment: The problem is that the genus is defined for *compact* analytic curves, which are actually algebraic.

Comment: Oh, right, thank you very much!

Comment: In higher dimensions the question https://mathoverflow.net/q/372885/175381 describes a hypothetical definition and Faltings theorem does have higher-dimensional generalizations so there might be something non-trivial there. Also note that there is a non-algebraic map from the upper half-plane to hyperbolic curves that might be relevant to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I think the best known results are the work of Bombieri and Pila and further work using the determinant method. This doesn't give finiteness but gives very applicable bounds.

Comment: Okay, thank you!